# sql developer does not recognize BIGINT type

Tags: sql

I'm trying to code in sql developer, and I want to declare a BIGINT variable, for using it later to store a big number. The problem is that sql developer does not recognize this type:

> Error report -
>
> ORA-06550: line 5, column 11:
>
> PLS-00201: identifier 'BIGINT' must be declared

What's the problem ? Do I have to do any updates or... ?

**EDIT**:

Ok, so I just want to do the following:

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
  v_numar NUMBER(19);

BEGIN

  FOR i IN 1..500000 
   LOOP
    v_numar := v_numar + 1;
   END LOOP;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('numar -> '||v_numar);
END;
```

The problem is that the output is just this:

> anonymous block completed
>
> numar ->

It can't print the value of v_numar. Why is that ? I declared the variabile as a NUMBER(19), as someone suggested earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesnot support `BIGINT` datatype.

Equivalent of `BIGINT` in oracle is `NUMBER(19)`

for more info check here
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/apa.htm

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @miTzuliK - Looks like this is a new question. It completely changed the context of original question

Comment: I suppose I will just make a new question for that.

Comment: Ah, I solve it. I just forgot to initialize the variable. Tiny things make the difference... again !